# how does this even compile

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memset

I just went to look back at old piece of code I've written some time back and saw something like this:

```
memset(LocRunTimeInfo[LabelId],0x00,sizeof(mpls_RuntimeInfo_t));
```

should that not instead be:

```
memset(LocRunTimeInfo + LabelId,0x00,sizeof(mpls_RuntimeInfo_t));
```

The declartation of LocRunTimeInfo looks like:

```
static mpls_RuntimeInfo_t *LocRunTimeInfo = NULL;
```

I have detailed the declaration of `mpls_RuntimeInfo_s` below:

```
typedef struct mpls_RuntimeInfo_s {
    UINT16 u16LabelId;
    jpax_egrobstr_t *pEgrObj;
    bcm_l3_intf_t l3_intf;
    bcm_mpls_vpn_config_t vpn_info;
    bcm_gport_t provider_gport;
    bcm_gport_t mpls_p_port_id;
    UINT8 smac[6];
    UINT16 u16ProviderVid;
} mpls_RuntimeInfo_t;
```

Comment: Is `mpls_RuntimeInfo_t` *itself* a pointer type?

Comment: Something tells me that this is going to be a deeply layered onion, but the next step is to show the definition of `mpls_RuntimeInfo_t`, and you may as well keep on peeling until you get down to the built-in primitive types.

Comment: @user3386109: I don't see that: even _if_ `mpls_RuntimeInfo_t` was a pointe type, the `memset` would just zero the array entry. The first version is just wrong under the given prerequisites. Unless there's turtles all the way down, of course.

Comment: Without the definition of `mpls_RuntimeInfo_t`, the best anybody can do is guess unless they've already encountered this before. Typically, a problem like this is that the `typedef` ends up doing something like `typedef struct mpls_rtinfo_ *mpls_RuntimeInfo_t;` or `typedef uint32_t mpls_RuntimeInfo_t;`. The result is that you pass a pointer that you didn't realize was a pointer, or you pass an integer that gets implicitly converted to a pointer. The former case highlights the dangers of using `typedef` to hide pointers while the latter would have been caught if you had compiled with `-Wall`.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Ok, I forgot about implicit int-pointer conversion. My bad, I normally have all warnings enabled and do not accept such crap.

Comment: @Olaf If you have `int array[5]` and you `memset(array[i],0,sizeof(int))`, then you'll get a warning from the compiler because you're implicitly casting an `int` to a pointer. However if you declare `int * array[5]` (an array of pointers), then `memset(array[i],0,sizeof(int))` is perfectly valid and zeros whatever `array[i]` points to. So if `mpls_RuntimeInfo_t` is a pointer type, then the OPs code is OK as is. BTW, I didn't downvote your answer. In fact, if the OP fixes the question, you can update your answer, and I'll upvote it for you.

Comment: @user3386109: I already voted to close that question, as I agree that there is information missing.

Comment: @user3386109: Just a sidenote: "if you declare int * array[5] (an array of pointers ...": For the question that would imply `typedef int *mpls_RuntimeInfo_t`. Then  `memset(LocRunTimeInfo[LabelId], ...` zero out an `int`, but `sizeof(mpls_RuntimeInfo_t)` is the size of a pointer, not an `int`.

Comment: @Olaf That's a good point, I hadn't thought of that. The mystery deepens... Oh well, I added a vote to close till the OP fixes the question.

Comment: please see **EDIT B** above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe first version (`LocRunTimeInfo[LabelId]`) is missing the address operator: `&LocRunTimeInfo[LabelId]` would be correct. Without that, it returns `struct mpls_RuntimeInfo_s`, not the required pointer to it.

`LocRunTimeInfo + LabelId` is also correct, as that is [identical](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2) to the correct version. The text in the standard shows getting the entry itself, but `&*(ptr + index)` is identical to `(ptr + index)`.

Note that `LocRunTimeInfo` should point to an array of sufficient size; the *null pointer* it has after initialization results in *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: You misread your link.  `ptr[idx]` is identical to `*(ptr + idx)`, not to `ptr + idx`.

Comment: <del>There is no address-of operator in the OP's code.</del> I see now that you are suggesting that the OP *should have* written an address-of operator.  You could stand to be less terse.

Comment: @zwol: Redundancy is bad. However, I edited. You might tolerate there are non-native speakers posting which do not find the correct wording at first edit. May I kindly ask to remove the downvote then?

Comment: I removed my downvote, but this is still not a terribly good answer to the question -- to be fair, I expect we cannot give a *good* answer without additional information.

Comment: @zwol: I agree. And I'm actually willing to vote to close as for a missing MCVE.

Comment: please see **EDIT B** above

Comment: @cerr: edited. It was beasically as I assumed. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Olaf yes, it does help, thank you but I still don't understand how it even compiled, using`Locum to eInfo [Labelid]` dereferences the value and I would expect `memset` not to accept that where `LocRunTimeInfo + LabelId` should work fine as it just moves up the poster. .. thanks!

Comment: @cerr: As I have no idea about your toolchain or settings, any answer would just be speculation. But even **if** it compiled, question is if it works as expected or the fault just passes unnoticed (would neither be the first, nor the last such fault).